# How find this sum of binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n+k}{k}2^k$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How  Find this sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n+k}{k}2^k$$

My idea: since
$$\binom{n+k}{k}k=\dfrac{(n+k)!}{n!(k-1)!}$$
and I have other idea: Consider
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{k}x^k$$
then
$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n+k}{k}x^{k-1}$$

But $f$ I can't find the closed form.($f(1/2)=2^n$,can see this link)

I find sometimes to find this
[Proof of the identity $2^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} \binom{n+k}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389099/proof-of-the-identity-2n-sum-limits-k-0n-2-k-binomnkk)  or can see  [Prove the following relation:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228339/prove-the-following-relation)
(But  my question is  different this )

This wolf can't :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7Dk*2%5Ek*%5Cbinom%7Bn%2Bk%7D%7Bk%7D

Thank you

Comment: You can have a closed form in terms of hypergeometric function.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal,why? Thank you

Comment: It is really new. I've seen $2^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} \binom{n+k}{k}$, but you cannot use this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Mhenni Benghorbal $$S(m)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n+k}{k}m^k$$ has a closed form which involves the hypergeometric function. Playing with this summation, I arrived to something "rather" simple which write $$S(m)=m (n+1) \left((-1)^n-\binom{2 n+1}{n+1} (m-1)^{n+2} m^n \, _2F_1(1,2n+2;n+1;m)\right)$$ I do not see how a simpler rigorous closed form could be obtained.